# Error importing plugin "sqlalchemy.ext.mypy.plugin": cannot import name 'Optional' from 'mypy.plugin'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mypy

Following the documentation here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/mypy.html I got an error while running mypy on any file using sqlalchemy mypy plugin.

**To Reproduce**

Create a new virtualenv using Python 3.8

```
pip install sqlalchemy[mypy]==1.4
```

Create a simple mypy config (mypy.ini)

> [mypy] plugins = sqlalchemy.ext.mypy.plugin

Run mypy on any file

```
mypy --config-file=mypy.ini
```

**Error**

> Error importing plugin "sqlalchemy.ext.mypy.plugin": cannot import
> name 'Optional' from 'mypy.plugin'

**Versions.**

OS: Linux Ubuntu 22.04

Python: 3.8

SQLAlchemy: 1.4

mypy: 0.991

Comment: What is your question? Have you reported the bug to the SQLAlchemy issue tracker?

Comment: Can't reproduce (Python 3.8, SQLA 1.4.44, mypy 0.991).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy2-stubs/issues/241) the problem is the SQLAlchemy version.
SQLAlchemy 1.4.0 is not supported.

Using SQLAlchemy 1.4.44 solved the problem.